# How to find the transformation matrix of this linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

[image]

Does transformation here mean change of basis or simply that T(ei) = ei'

ei, ei' being the given bases.

Thanks

Comment: How is $\beta'$ an ordered basis? Its elements aren't even all of the same dimension.

Comment: The first element is missing, assume it to be any entry that make it an ordered basis. I am more interested in understanding the question.

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to find $[I]^{e}_{\beta '}\cdot [I]_{e}^{\beta}= [I]^{\beta}_{\beta '}$ Where $e$ is the standard basis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you understand the question correctly: you must find a linear transformation (matrix) $T$ such that $T\beta_i=\beta'_i$. (and $\beta'_1$ is indeed missing an element, presumably a typo in the question).

A straightforward way of solving this is to construct a $3\times 3$ matrix $T$ with unknown elements, then demand $T\beta_i=\beta'_i$, which gives you 9 linear equations in the 9 unknowns $T_{ij}$, which you can solve.